# When not to index database?

Tags: database, indexing

We create indexes on database to speed up search queries by reducing the number of records/rows in a table that need to be analyzed or worked.

This query is asked to me in interview that when not to index database, I answered that when database is small, having less number of columns, and when space id matter. But the interviewer not so much agreed.

What are the main reasons when not to index the database?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the number of records is small (e.g. below 50,000 - the real number depends on hardware, is it PC or embedded device, RAM, CPU).
2. If you have intensive inserts/updates and rare selects. Data modification become heavy if there are (many) indexes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few scenarios where adding an index might not be beneficial.

1. You always read all records in the table and you have frequent writes. In this scenario an index has no benefit and would just slows down the writes
2. The number of writes is significantly higher than reads and you do not care about the read performance. For example, if you log to a table in production, you may want this to be as fast as possible. As you generally only query this table when an error occurs, you may be happy to perform a table scan.